# Can vagrant and ansible playbook be run "inside" of pipenv on macOS

Tags: python, ansible, vagrant, pipenv

I am using macOS and there I have created pip env. After I activate pip env, I install ansible in created virenv. After I activate this virenv terminal, I run vagrant up in this terminal.

Is this good practice ?

My motivation to do this:
I want to avoid whole mess with pip packages and version on macOS. I use vagrant for testing my ansilbe playbooks.

Comment: you need to reword your question. It isn't very clear where you are trying to do things.

Mac is your host operating system. Vagrant is launching your virtual machine... Ansible is able to manage several different operating systems, and you can execute python inside a virtual environment....

so the answer is "yes"?

You instead want to know how to do it.. well, it is still not clear what you want to do. Is ansible supposed to run inside the virtual machine or on the host operating system?

Answer (score 0):

He wants Ansible to run in the virtual environment created using Pipenv not on one of the target (testing) virtual machines.  Thus, he can port his entire virtual environment to any machine and in theory it is clean from the OS Python, etc. packages while being exactly reproducible as code.  The Vagrant VMs are only for testing machines to run the playbooks against before going on to another development or production platform.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).